# Finding the exact value of an infinite sum.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Estimate the value of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^3}$ within $0.011$ of the exact value. 
I got $1.198$ by solving for

$$\sum _{n=1}^4\frac{1}{n^3}+\int _5^{\infty }\frac{1}{x^3}dx$$

but it is not the correct answer. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Your approximation looks fine to me. The error $\left|\sum\limits_{n=5}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3}  - \int_5^\infty \frac{dx}{x^3}\right|  \sim 0.00439 < 0.011$.

Comment: You are within about $0.004$ of the exact answer, so what you have already is better than what you are asking for. The exact value is represented by $\zeta(3)$ and is equal to about $1.202057$.

Comment: The Riemann zeta function is actually designed for this kind of problem, as $$\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s}$$